# I need help on how to delete image from a folder stored in the database, PHP unlink() not working

Tags: javascript, php

I am a newbie. The main app is for house listings. Each house address is used(as filename) to store all images of a particular house in a folder. The folder path is then saved in the database.
The below code is a part of the main app; it is for updating the folder in database(delete an image and update). I have searched the net to no avail. Help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

1. displayImage($imgs, $pathimg) is for displaying the images each with delete button.
2. The javaScript myimageDelete() is working; removes the image from the screen.
3. However, the php phpUnlink($pathimg, $pic) is not working. I am not able to unlink() the deleted image.
4. I called the PHP function in the js function it did not work.
5. I need help to unlink am image and update the folder and database

```
<?php
include './db.conn.php';
include './header.php';
?>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
  $address = $_POST['img_addr1'];
  $id = $_POST['prop_Id'];

  if (isset($path)) {
    $path1 = $pathimg;
    $total_img = scandir($path1);
    $sql = "UPDATE `list_tble` SET `img_addr`='$path1' WHERE prop_Id=$id";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
  }
}
?>


<div class=" d-flex flex-column mx-auto bg-secondary mb-2" style="width: 500px; height:300px;">
  <div id="image_preview" class="bg-light w-100 h-20 d-flex  flex-wrap overflow-auto mb-2" style="border: 6px solid grey">
    <?php
    displayImage($imgs, $pathimg);

    ?>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<?php
function displayImage($imgs, $pathimg)
{
  if (count($imgs) > 2) {
    foreach (array_splice($imgs, 2) as $pic) {
      echo '<form method="POST" id="small_img" class="dis_Image bg-warning mx-auto d-flex flex-column" style="width: 120px; height: 120px;">    <img src ="' . $pathimg . '/' . $pic . '" width="120px" height="120px" style="border:2px solid white" alt="House list image" />
      <input name="img_del" type="text" class="spanImage w-100 bg-danger fw-bold mx-auto" 
            style="cursor: pointer; color: white; font-size= 18px;" 
            onclick="myimageDelete()" value="DELETE" /> 
            </form>';
    }
  } else {
    echo "Directory is Empty.";
  }
}
?>

<?php
function phpUnlink($pathimg, $pic)
{
  if (isset($_POST['img_del'])) {
    $imgToUnlink = $pathimg . '/' . $pic;
    if (!unlink($imgToUnlink)) {
      echo "$imgToUnlink is not deleted";
    } else {
      echo "$imgToUnlink is deleted";
    }
  }
}
?>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  function myimageDelete() {
    event.target.parentNode.remove();    
  }
</script>

<?php
include './footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: Hi. Have you tried to display the return value of unlink($imgToUnlink), as well as the value of $imgToUnlink? With this information can you verify that the path to the file to be deleted is correct?

Comment: I just tried to print_r($imgToUnlink) inside the phpUnlink(), when I called it nothing appeared.

Comment: So, if empty, no file is deleted ;) You need to fill in the path to the file to delete https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php